# How can I delete a column in a multi-dimensional Laravel collection?

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

I just want to delete a column from a multi-dimensional collection.

```
$z = collect(
    ["x"=>"a", "y"=>"b", "z"=>"c"],
    ["x"=>"c", "y"=>"d", "z"=>"e"]
);

$z->deleteColumn("x");
```

$z should now have the data set:

```
[
   ["y"=>"b", "z"=> "c"]
   ["y"=>"d", "z"=> "e"]
]
```

I can use a map function with except but is there an easy one liner I'm missing?
This seems pretty common.

Comment: avoid using "easiest way", "best way" etcc in writing your questions otherwise you get the downvotes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [`transform()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-transform) method:

```
$collection->transform(function($i) {
    unset($i->x);
    return $i;
});
```

Answer (score 13):

It is better to set what is needed, instead of deleting what is not needed. You will have easily scalable and modifiable code.

Use the [`transform()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-transform) method along with `only()`:

```
$collection->transform(function($item) {
    return $item->only(['y', 'z']);
});
```

Comment: Does this make a duplicate array? Or is it modifying the original array?

Answer (score 4):

Using `Arr::except()` is a good option to avoid listing all the keys you need:

```php
$collection->transform(function(array $item) {
    return Arr::except($item, 'x');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$syncData = $z->map(function($attr){
     return Arr::only($attr, ['y', 'z']);
});
```

Laravel 8.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck) method, like so:

```
$z = collect([
    ["x"=>"a", "y"=>"b"],
    ["x"=>"c", "y"=>"d"]
);

$z = $z->pluck('y');
//["b", "d"]
```

Comment: This is technically correct however I want the reverse of pluck basically.

Pluck returns a set of columns from the collection.  I want to delete a set of columns from the collection and return those not-deleted.

Comment: Then you should pick @sapnesh-naik answer as the correct one, because forget method does what you just explained

Comment: I am unable to make the `forget` method delete a column from a multi-dimensional collection.  It just seems to delete keys from single-dimensional collections.

Comment: You can then try @AlexeyMezenin solution, it's not a one liner, but it does the job

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a macro to the Collection class.

```
/**
 * Pass array or string of key column names to remove
 */
Collection::macro('removeCols', function ($except) {
    if (!is_array($except)) $except = (array)$except;

    // Single Dimensional arrays
    if (!is_array($this->first()) && !is_object($this->first())) return $this->except($except);

    // Multi Dimensional arrays
    $out = $this->map(function ($item) use ($except) {
        $item = collect($item);
        return $item->except($except)->toArray();
    });

    return collect($out);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. You would want to optimize it because it looks like the code is memory consuming. For example, instead of converting each item to a collection, do an operation and convert it to an array, just use [`array_except()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-array-except) on the original array.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

one line solution

```
$collections->transform(fn ($item) => Arr::except($item, 'column'));
```